# Can't get IAMBufferNegotiation in my code, but GraphStudioNext shows ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES

Tags: c#, directshow, video-capture, latency, directshow.net

I am using DirectShowLib.net in C# and I am trying to set change my ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES settings, as I am using a live video source and changes are not "immediately" visible on screen.

When constructing a filter graph in GraphStudioNext the ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES show for the upstream and the downstream pin, although only after connection.

[image: Filter graph showing that ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES can be retrieved by GraphStudioNext for both the capture filter and the video decoder.]

I'd like to set the ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES using IAMBufferNegotiation, but when trying to get the interface from my capture filter (AV/C Tape Recorder/Player) I get an E_UNEXPECTED (0x8000ffff) error. Here is the relevant C# code:

```
DS.IAMBufferNegotiation iamb = (DS.IAMBufferNegotiation)capturePin;
DS.AllocatorProperties allocatorProperties = new DS.AllocatorProperties();
hr = iamb.GetAllocatorProperties(allocatorProperties);
DS.DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
```

When I used the downstream video decoder input pin, I get a System.InvalidCastException as the interface is not supported.

How I can I change the cBuffers value of ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES?

Comment: What latency do you have? With a DV-Device a latency of 3-5 frames should be normal. Less latency is not possible in a digital video workflow.

Comment: It was approx. 20 frames, but in the end I found the problem to be outside the filter chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing number of buffers is not going to help you here. The number of buffers are negotiated between filters are are, basically, not to be changed externally, however in your case there is no real buffering in the pipeline: once the video frame is available on the first output pin, then it immediately goes through and reaches video renderer. If you see a delay there, it means that either DV player has internal latency, or it is time stamping frames "late" and video renderer has to wait before presentation. You can troubleshoot the latter case by inserting Smart Tee Filter in between and connecting its Preview output pin downward to the video renderer - if this helps out, then the issue is frame time stamping on the source. Amount of buffers does not cause any presentation lag here.

Comment: Hi! The problem was not in the filter chain. I had a samplegrabber added as well. I passed the buffer content to a third party software and eventhough it was in different thread it apparently still caused some lagging. I restructered the code and it is working now, but I don't know yet exactly what removed the problem.